# How to make url like this in YII2?

Tags: yii2

I am using yii2.I have problem related to url structure. How I can change URL structure in Yii2 my current URL as  given below.

```
http://localhost/advanced/posts/view?id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

By configuring the urlManager component in the application configuration, you can let your application recognize arbitrary URL formats without modifying your existing application code. For example, you can use the following code to create a URL for the post/view action:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

// Url::to() calls UrlManager::createUrl() to create a URL
$url = Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100]);
```

Depending on the urlManager configuration, the created URL may look like one of the following (or other format). And if the created URL is requested later, it will still be parsed back into the original route and query parameter value.

```
/index.php?r=post%2Fview&id=100
/index.php/post/100
/posts/100
```

Config:

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

You can configure yii\web\UrlManager::$rules as an array with keys being the patterns and values the corresponding routes. Each pattern-route pair constructs a URL rule. For example, the following rules configuration declares two URL rules. The first rule matches a URL posts and maps it into the route post/index. The second rule matches a URL matching the regular expression post/(\d+) and maps it into the route post/view and defines a query parameter named id.

```
'rules' => [
    'posts' => 'post/index',
    'post/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view',
]
```

The answer was given to you using official documentation: [Routing and URL Creation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)